# Display the name and runs scored by the player (as a batsman) who has taken the highest number of wickets (as a bowler)

Tags: sqlite

SELECT player, runs From batting WHERE player = (SELECT max(WicketsTaken) FROM bowling);

This is what i have so far. It runs this way but outputs nothing. I need it to output the player and runs from batting based on the highest score in wickets taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong column in `where` clause to refer wickets taken columns data. Change `player` column to your `WicketsTaken` in where clause

```
  SELECT player, runs From batting 
  WHERE player in (SELECT 
  Player FROM bowling where
    WicketsTaken =
   (Select max(WicketsTaken) from 
    bowling );
```

Comment: WicketsTaken are not part of the Batting table so it will not run.

Comment: That one does work. I figured it out after you had given me the first part. Thank you very much for the help.